# Adding Scripts to Nop Commerce plugin

Tags: plugins, nopcommerce

I am trying to add bootstrap to a Payment Plugin that I am developing and I do not know why it's not including the files in OnePageChekout page that includes  the PaymentInfo.cshtml partial view...

Code:

```
@model Nop.Plugin.Payments.PluginName.Domain.PluginModel

@{
    Layout = "";

    Html.AddScriptParts("~/Plugins/Payments.PluginName/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js");
    Html.AddCssFileParts("~/Plugins/Payments.PluginName/Content/bootstrap.min.css");
}
@using Nop.Web.Framework.UI
```

Tried this as well:

```
@model Nop.Plugin.Payments.PluginName.Domain.PluginModel

@{
    Layout = "";

    Html.AddScriptParts(ResourceLocation.Foot,"~/Plugins/Payments.PluginName/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js", true);
    Html.AddCssFileParts(ResourceLocation.Head, "~/Plugins/Payments.PluginName/Content/bootstrap.min.css");
}
@using Nop.Web.Framework.UI
```

Tried to use *Html.AppendCssFileParts* and Html.AppendScriptFileParts and it did not worked.

[image]
[image]
When debugging...the code calls this functions and it's adding the file references to the _scriptsParts and _cssParts variables.

But at that moment it adds my scripts those variables do not have any more scripts which I think it's odd.

Also it never calls the GenerateCssFiles function which I think is the function that adds the scripts to the bundle because this is only called after the page (OnePageCheckout.cshtml) is loaded and **never when a partial view is loaded in the main view**.

Am I right in this assumptions ? How can I add scripts dynamically to the PaymentInfo.cshtml page ?

Comment: Maybe a stupid idea but are your scripts defined in your solution as content files with "copy if newer" or "copy always" ?

Comment: They are defined as "Copy always" I actually tried to go to the specific script url in the browser and it opens perfect so the path is correct. Otherwise I would have a 404. Thanks